# Wrong Text Placement in GetOrgChart

Tags: getorgchart

I've got Wrong Text Placement during rendering of each node in **GetOrgChart**.[Please see the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgZfM.jpg)
Please Help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why But I realized that the only way to adjust X or Y Positioning of text node in **GetOrgChart** is modifying the **textPoints** OR **textPointsNoImages** based on whether we have image node or not in related theme Array.